# Unable to run edit() command in RStudio

Tags: r

I have just started out on R and have hit a roadblock. I can't seem to run the edit() command in RStudio.
Here's what I have tried
1. Changing the RSTUDIO_WHICH_R environment variable
2. Fixing the warning messages which were displayed every time I opened the RStudio.
3. I have even reinstalled R and RStudio.

I have posted the image of the error message that I get on my Console window.

I am working on MacOS High Sierra

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Console error message]

4. I have installed Xcode as well and the error has changed as shown in the second image.
   [Error Message after installing Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys2T0.png)

Comment: Are you using Mac OS? As the error message says: **missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun** You can try this and see if it helps: http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/

Comment: On terminal `xcode-select --install`, I believe you need to update/install xcode to make it work

Comment: @PKumar, I installed Xcode as well but I still get the error. But this time, I don't get the xcrun error. The new error message is the same as in the screenshot but it doesn't contain the first two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing or have to reinstall [XQuartz 2.7.11](https://www.xquartz.org/releases/XQuartz-2.7.11.html), install it first then try running edit command.If it doesn't work then do the following.(This happens sometimes during an update)

1) Find the location of libcario.2.dylib using `locate` command from terminal/iterm-2 . Use command `locate libcario.2.dylib`, you should receive something similar with this location: `/usr/X11/lib/libcario.2.dylib`. Someone can use `cd`,`find` to locate the location as well.

2) If the location is found then use `ln -s` to create a link like below:
`sudo ln -s  /opt/X11 /usr/X11`

Comment: I located libcairo.2.dylib at /opt/X11/lib/libcairo.2.dylib . What should be the link command? I apologise. I am new at using terminal in MacOS

Comment: @Regime, its written there

Comment: I have installed Xquartz. The doubt I have is that you used the location /usr/X11/lib/ whereas I found it in /opt/X11/lib. Will the command still stay the same?

Comment: @Regime you have to do it this way: sudo `ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11`, the idea is to create soft link at your user level

Comment: Thanks @PKumar. This fixed it!